# Images are not displaying at server?

Tags: html, web

At first I have to tell you that I have very less knowledge about this. So I can explain it as simple as it is.

I made a website on my xampp localhost server which give me this :

**Result:**

[image]

You can see these are just two image. nothing special in it.

but when i upload it on web server it shows nothing.

You can see this [**Link**](http://hsbtextilesourcing.com/test/).

I know it is show 404 error but images are on server.

[image]

Comment: Your server is case-sensitive. Change the filenames to `*.JPG` ( eg. `leg(2).JPG` ). ;)

Comment: but my other images are working fine just these two images are having problem

Comment: Please show us the code for your other images. Either those file extensions are not capitalized or you have already capitalized them in your code.

Comment: Perhaps you named them `*.jpg*`?

Comment: @showdev http://hsbtextilesourcing.com/#product you can see my site every image is written in .jpg but these two were not working working.

Comment: Every other image has a lower-cased extension, which your code correctly references. Those two "problem" images have upper-cased extensions, which must be referenced as such in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your file extensions should be capitalized.

In your code the images are referenced as :

```html
<img src="leg(2).jpg" alt="leg warmers">
<img src="leg(1).jpg" alt="leg warmers">
```

But on disk, their extensions are capitalized:

http://hsbtextilesourcing.com/test/leg(1).JPG
http://hsbtextilesourcing.com/test/leg(2).JPG

Change your code to this:

```
<img src="leg(2).JPG" alt="leg warmers">
<img src="leg(1).JPG" alt="leg warmers">
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is right but he/she answer first!

Comment: No, Doc and I answered first. But it's not important. You can accept whichever answer you like best!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're running Windows locally - which happens to be not case sensitive. Your server is probably running some flavor of Linux - which is case sensitive.
Change your links:

```
<img src="leg(2).JPG" alt="leg warmers">
<img src="leg(1).JPG" alt="leg warmers">
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i still have a question why my other images are working fine but these two were not!

Comment: are your other images in the proper case? I looked at a few and they seem to be ending .jpg - so they are expected to work just fine